# Why does du -k display block counts in 4096-byte blocks even though it says 1024?

Tags: filesystems, command-line-interface, filesize, du

When I ran this

```
du -k *
```

I expected the output for each file to be `ceil(filesize/1024)` but the output was `ceil(filesize/4096) * 4`. Why is that?

Description of -k in `$ man du`: *Display block counts in 1024-byte (1-Kbyte) blocks.*

I'm using OS X if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

The file system allocates space in units of 4K (4096 bytes).   If you create a 1 byte file, the file system will allocate 4K of storage to hold the file.

The `du -k` command reports the total storage used by the file system.  So `du -k` reports that the file system is using 4K of space for that file.

Comment: So what does this description mean then? **Display block counts in 1024-byte (1-Kbyte) blocks.**

Comment: It means `du` will round the space up to units of 1024.  If you were running on a file system with a smaller unit of allocation (say 512 bytes) then `du` would round up to 1024 byte units. E.g., if the file system reported that a file used 512 bytes, `du -k` would round up and report the file using 1 KB.  This is what `du -g` does.  A file's size might be 123 bytes as reported by `ls`. `du -k` will report it as 4K, as explained above. `du -g` would round this up to the nearest GB and report it using 1GB.